# Android: Change CardView Layout on Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-orientation

So I've spent a day on this one and it's time to turn to the pros on StackOverflow.

I am working with `RecyclerView` and `CardView` to display cards that contain text and an image.  In portrait it looks great but in landscape there is space on both sides of the image instead of being flush with the edge of the card.  I cannot change the dimensions of the image so I would like to change the XML of the `CardView` on orientation change, like you can do with a Fragment or Activity.

Is this possible and how could this be implemented?  The only thought I have now would be to have another `ViewHolder` inside of my `RecyclerViewAdapter` that is used when checking for orientation returns Landscape.  I'm hoping for a simpler solutions.  Thanks in advance guys.

CardView XML.  Notice that the width of the card is set to `match_parent`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView           
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/placeCard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/ripple"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rippleForeground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/articleImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="228dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paletteView"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abstractTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder" />


                <!--<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/placeholder"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>-->


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/globalTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/abstractTextView"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/paletteView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/articleImageView"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a layout_land folder in res and copy your xml to it.You will use xml in this folder if your orientation is Landscape.You can change the xml in this folder to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the image in the xml like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/articleImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="228dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```